# How can I change title of audio?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I trying to send audio file with my telegram bot to myself, upload to telegram server and getting file_id at first:

```
response = requests.post(
url='https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/{1}'.format(token, method),
data={'chat_id': v, 'audio': 
'http://www.largesound.com/ashborytour/sound/brobob.mp3'}).json()
print(response)
```

then I've got this response

```
{'duration': 29, 'mime_type': 'audio/mpeg', 'file_id': 
'CQADBAADCAADVt71UQINbAiCs0snAg', 'file_size': 355968}
```

how can I resend audio by file_id with my own title of audio? Because if I do

```
response = requests.post(
url='https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/{1}'.format(token, method),
data={'chat_id': v, 'audio': 'CQADBAADCAADVt71UQINbAiCs0snAg', 'title': 'Awesome bass', 'perfomer': 'Bass'}).json()
```

I've got mp3 file from my bot with name brobob.mp3, so title change did not work. What I did wrong? Or how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 15 minutes and here is answer (using PyTelegramBotApi):

```
file_id = response['result']['audio']['file_id']
path = bot.get_file(file_id)
file = path.file_path
download = bot.download_file(file)
bot.send_audio(chat_id=v, audio=download, title="Awesome bass", 
performer="Bass", duration=120)
```